# Is there a Hebrew Calendar discussion place?

Tags: torah-study, calendar, tishrei, molad

Well, is there? I mean a Torah-observant place, if possible, where they discuss the math and the system behind the current calendar, original sources, perhaps the history involved in it as well ([the machlokes involving Rav Saadia Gaon and R' Aharon ben Meir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saadia_Gaon#Dispute_with_Ben_Meir) would be an example of something else they might deal with, even if it is only partly about our current calendar).

Comment: Please be more specific ... about the math behind the current calendar? About the Jewish holidays? What sort of place did you have in mind?

Comment: Edited it a little to get rid of the implication that it needs to be a discussion group - though I'd like to see one of those if there is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On https://kosherjava.com/ you will get much about the **math and system** behind the Hebrew Calendar among other things.

At https://www.daat.ac.il/he-il/hagim/luach_ivri (*in Hebrew*), you can view a bunch of general articles about the Hebrew Calendar which also include **history**.

These two (especially the latter) will discuss **original sources**.

Comment: Are those places to have discussions?

Comment: if MicholeR's definition of "discuss" is a chat group then no, these would not fit the bill (and I would have misunderstood the intent).  If "discuss" here means articles or blog entries which list and mention and delve into calendar issues then those sites will have some relevant content.

Comment: Rabbi Heber from the startK is who you want to listen to.

Comment: Thank you, these are great!

Comment: Kosherjava looks great, but I'm not seeing that much overall on the calendar. It's almost all about zmanim as far as I can tell.